# Pegar valor de data-attr e inserir em outro elemento

Tags: jquery, html5, bootstrap-3

Tenho uma listagem dinâmica com PHP, e quando clicar em uma "< tr> " da tabela que é listada, deve abrir um modal com varias informaçoes. O que pretendo fazer, é atribuir certos valores da listagem para Data-attributes, e com Jquery, pretendo pegar os valores desses data-* e colocar no conteúdo desse modal que vai ser aberto. Aí tenho apenas um data-* e um campo, pois creio que fazendo funcionar um, dê pra fazer com outro.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 
 $(".teste").click(function(){
  
  var val = $(".teste").data("pro");
  $("#pro").val(val);
  });
 });
</script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<table class="table">
   <tr data-toggle="modal" class="teste" data-target="#exampleModal" data-pro="teste">
        <td>teste</td>
        <td>teste</td>
        <td>teste</td>
        <td>teste</td>
 </tr>
</table> 

<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
     <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
     <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">OS nº1226</h5>
     <label>
      Emissão: dd/mm/yyyy
     </label>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-12">
       Nome: fulano de tal da silva
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-6">
       CPF: 000.000.000-00
        </div>
       <div class="col-md-6">
       Telefone: (00)0000-0000
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-4">
       Veículo: brasilia 
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-4">
       Placa: abc-0000
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-4">
       Status: 
       <form class="select_OS">
        <select>
          <option value="nenhum">--status--</option>
          <option value="emitida">Emitida</option>
          <option value="em_orcamento">Em orçamento</option>
          <option value="aguardando">Aguardando resp.cliente</option>
          <option value="aguardando">Ordem autorizada</option>
          <option value="em_exec">Em Execução</option>
          <option value="finalizada">Finalizada</option>
        </select>
       </form>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-12" id="pro">
       Defeito apresentado:
       <p>
       </p>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-12">
       Solução:
       <br>
       <p>
        solucao
        solucao
        solucao
       
       </p>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar janela</button>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Salvar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
     </div>
   </div> 
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</script>
<!-- bootstrap -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Substitua `$("#pro").val(val);` por `$("#pro").text(val);` ou `$("#pro").html(val);`. O `.val()` serve apenas para elementos de formulário.

Comment: Não rodou. Se puder tentar fazer funcionar com esse meu código pra eu poder ver o que está dando errado

Comment: https://hastebin.com/ejuvelenov.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crie um `span` na `div` `#pro` que irá receber o valor do dataset:

```
<div class="col-md-12" id="pro">
   Defeito apresentado: <span></span>
   <p>
   </p>
</div>
```

E use `$(this)` no evento para pegar o dataset da linha clicada, e mude o seletor e o método para `.text`:

```
$(".teste").click(function(){
   var val = $(this).data("pro");
   $("#pro span").text(val);
   });
});
```

**Exemplo:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 
   $(".teste").click(function(){
      var val = $(this).data("pro");
      $("#pro span").text(val);
      });
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<table class="table">
   <tr data-toggle="modal" class="teste" data-target="#exampleModal" data-pro="teste1">
        <td>teste</td>
        <td>teste</td>
        <td>teste</td>
        <td>teste</td>
 </tr>
   <tr data-toggle="modal" class="teste" data-target="#exampleModal" data-pro="teste2">
        <td>teste</td>
        <td>teste</td>
        <td>teste</td>
        <td>teste</td>
 </tr>
</table> 

<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
     <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
     <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">OS nº1226</h5>
     <label>
      Emissão: dd/mm/yyyy
     </label>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-12">
       Nome: fulano de tal da silva
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-6">
       CPF: 000.000.000-00
        </div>
       <div class="col-md-6">
       Telefone: (00)0000-0000
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-4">
       Veículo: brasilia 
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-4">
       Placa: abc-0000
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-4">
       Status: 
       <form class="select_OS">
        <select>
          <option value="nenhum">--status--</option>
          <option value="emitida">Emitida</option>
          <option value="em_orcamento">Em orçamento</option>
          <option value="aguardando">Aguardando resp.cliente</option>
          <option value="aguardando">Ordem autorizada</option>
          <option value="em_exec">Em Execução</option>
          <option value="finalizada">Finalizada</option>
        </select>
       </form>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-md-12" id="pro">
                        Defeito apresentado: <span></span>
                        <p>
                        </p>
                     </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-12">
       Solução:
       <br>
       <p>
        solucao
        solucao
        solucao
       
       </p>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar janela</button>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Salvar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
     </div>
   </div>
```